# estimation with Sobolev Space $L^2(0,T,H^1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

if we have the relation 
$$
\dfrac{1}{2} ||w||^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + ||\nabla w||^2_{L^2((0,T);L^2(\Omega))} \leq ||f||_{L^2((0,T);L^2(\Omega))} ||w||_{L^2((0,T);L^2(\Omega))} 
$$
where $f$ is data, how we prouve that 
$$
||w||_{L^2((0,T),H^1(\Omega))} \leq R,
$$
where $R$ is constant?

Thank's in advance to the help.

Comment: Questions are much better received if you include what you tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a nice application for Young's inequality
$$
a b \le \frac12 a^2 + \frac12 b^2
\qquad\forall a,b\ge 0.$$
(Note that this can be proven by expanding $(a-b)^2$).

Now, by replacing $a$ with $a \, \sqrt\varepsilon$ and $b$ with $b/\sqrt\varepsilon$,
we find
$$
a b \le \frac{\varepsilon}2 a^2 + \frac1{2\,\varepsilon} b
\qquad\forall a,b \ge 0, \varepsilon > 0.$$
This is very useful, since the coefficient in front of $a^2$ can be made arbitrarily small.

You just need to apply this inequality with $a = \|w\|_{L^2(L^2)}$, $b = \|f\|_{L^2(L^2)}$ and $\varepsilon = 1/2$.

Comment: If we apply Young, we obtain that $$  ||w||^2_{L^2}+ ||\nabla w||^2_{L^2(0,T,L^2)} \leq ||w||^2_{L^2(0,T,L^2)} + ||f||^2_{L^2(0,T,L^2)}$$, but how we deduce for this estimation on $||w||_{L^2(0,T,H^1)}$? Please

Comment: You get the factor $1/2$ in front of the $\|w\|_{L^2(L^2)}^2$ on the right-hand side. This allows you to move the term to the left-hand side. This gives $$\|w\|_{L^2(L^2)}^2 + \|\nabla w\|_{L^2(L^2)}^2 \le C \|f\|^2.$$ The left-hand side is now just the (squared) norm in $L^2(H^1)$.